# Using the blog for job posts and conference announcements

Tags: discussion, blog

This is just an idea. How about using the blog for job posts and/or conference announcements? Of course, only theory stuff. The [DMANET](http://dmatheorynet.blogspot.com/) mailing list is doing the same thing, but you always find stuff that is outside TCS.

Maybe this will spark interest in theorists who are not users.

We can also stick only to conferences, and for example keep a list of deadlines, events etc etc. Something like this http://www.dur.ac.uk/tom.friedetzky/conf.html

Answer (score 6):

I don't think we should have job posting on the blog. Unless it is a general blogpost like "How to get a job as a TCSer" which provides general career advice and sources. I would dislike individual posts about post-doc and faculty-positions.

As for conference announcements, I am still cautious. A general announcement like "conference XX's deadline is in a month, submit a paper and come to ski resort YY" I feel is not very useful for the cstheory blog. I would prefer if the advertiser also did a bit of a background on the field, or maybe important results from last years conference. For a focused topic-specific workshop or conference, an intro to the field followed by an announcement of the event would be interesting. This also forces advertisers to generate interesting content apart from simply announcing an event.

Answer (score 5):

For conferences, we already have confsearch.org. For example, you can simply construct a  URL such as http://www.confsearch.org/confsearch/faces/pages/staticresults.jsp?query=approx+cocoon+esa+focs+icalp+isaac+latin+soda+stacs+stoc+swat+wads+waoa&sortMode=1&graphicView=1 with your own favourite conferences and bookmark it.

Comment: this is really cool! I did not know about this tool

Answer (score 3):

That's a reasonable idea, though I'm not sure how much support there is for it, and maintaining a current jobs page is time consuming. As Artem implies, many readers probably won't want to be spammed with jobs announcements, however for those looking a central listing is an invaluable resource. If we were to do such a thing (and I'm not suggesting that we should or shouldn't) I think the way to do it would be via a static page rather than as blog posts. Adding a static page to the blog similar to the ABOUT page should be relatively simple. We would just need to be careful about removing jobs after the application deadline passes, or maybe 6 months from the original announcement for open "until filled" positions. We would also need to have a bunch of announcements lined up for the initial addition of the page. There is no point having a site with only 1 position advertised.

Comment: I think that putting conference information in a static page would be better. Like the example I gave before http://www.dur.ac.uk/tom.friedetzky/conf.html

Comment: I agree that a static page would be acceptable. However, I doubt we could find people interested in maintaining it (if there was people interested in maintaining such a page, then you'd think one would exist already)